# How to use v-maska for input?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, masking

I am using [v-maska](https://beholdr.github.io/maska/#/). I need to set up a mask for the amount of the type **100 200 500.99**. 99 cents - optionally, you can set it or not.

I have:
`<input ... v-maska :data-maska="9 99#.0" :data-maska-tokens="9:[0-9]:repeated|0:[0-9]:optional" data-maska-reversed />`
So I don't know how make it. Help, please!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the following mask: `<input ... v-maska :data-maska="9 999#.99" :data-maska-tokens="9:[0-9]:repeated|0:[0-9]:optional" data-maska-reversed />` This mask will allow you to input the number 100200500.99, with the optional 99 cents at the end.

Comment: I still get digits after '.', but it should be if i put '.' from keyboard. If I don't do anything I need to get 100200500